# Как получить URL загружаемого приложения в app store через swift

Tags: swift, swift3, mobile, apple, appstore

Можно ли как-то получить url страницы загруженного приложения в app store через swift?

Т.е. пользователь видит рекламную ссылку, переходит по ней на страницу нашего приложения в app store и загружает наше приложение.

Из загруженного приложения можно получить текущий url страницы в app store?

Comment: Вот непонятно что необходимо. Ссылка на приложение внутри приложения чтобы поставить это приложение?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите отследить, по какой из рекламных ссылок установили приложение, вы можете пойти таким путем:

1. Вместо ссылки на AppStore, ставите ссылку на ваш сайт, который
   запоминает id рекламы, IP и время, с которого открыли ссылку и
   делает редирект на AppStore.
2. При запуске приложения вы сверяете IP
   адрес пользователя (из приложения) и время (например, проверяете
   чтобы между нажатием на ссылку на скачивание и запуском приложения
   прошло не более 10 минут) с заранее сохраненными данными о открытых
   ссылках.

Теперь вы знаете по какой рекламной ссылке сколько человек установили ваше приложение и какая из ссылок наиболее эффективно привлекает пользователей.

Comment: Благодарю за совет!

Answer (score 0):

вот тут можно достать ссылку на ваше приложение (только нужно будет ее подредактировать немного) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл сделать поправку - при помощи swift

Answer (score 0):

URL страницы вашего приложения в App Store всегда один и тот же, зашейте его в ресурсы если надо.

Приложение понятия не имеет откуда его установили, система ему такой информации не предоставляет, при установке пользовательский код приложения не исполняется.